# how to install kjots in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kde, plasma

I'm trying to install kjots in ubuntu 16.04 and looks like the package is not available in ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -s kjots
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kjots is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  kdepim-doc

E: Package 'kjots' has no installation candidate
```

Anyone has any idea on how to install it ?

Enabled universe vivid repo, but still no luck.

```
$ sudo apt-get install kjots
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kjots : Depends: libkdepim4 (= 4:4.14.6-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libnoteshared4 (= 4:4.14.6-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpimcommon4 : Depends: libkdepim4 (= 4:4.14.6-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Looks like kjots is not ported to kdepim: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdepim

However, I found the source package of Kjots in github: https://github.com/KDE/kjots

Anyone has any idea on installing the same from source package?

Comment: Not sure if this is related but if I `apt-cache search kjots` i get the following output `gjots2 - Simple jotter (outline processor) for X11/gtk-gnome`. If this solves it I will move it to an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: CherryTree looks like a decent replacement for the defunct kjots, I can write this up if you are interested? http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/

Comment: actually, I want kjots because i have used it before and want to migrate my old books. so I think it only works in kjots.

Answer (score 0):

This means you perhaps don't have the correct repository open.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If universe is not included then modify the file so that it does.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe multiverse
```

then try installing.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kjots
```

Comment: Shouldn't that not be `xenial` instead of `vivid`? The OP is using 16.04.

Comment: You're absolutely  right.

Comment: @Videonauth But there is no installation candidate for Ubuntu 16.04. If OP must get `kjots`, he/she will have to deal with installing from a 14.04 repo.

Comment: But then still better downloading it as deb file from http://packages.ubuntu.com as doing a repo hack.

Comment: universe is already enabled, i have enabled vivid is also but it is not working

Comment: @VipinMs ,Have you tried to download and install it manually ? https://pkgs.org/download/kjots

Comment: That is not working, however I found the source package of kjots 5.0.1 in https://github.com/KDE/kjots. Not sure how to install it. Any one has any idea?

Comment: i managed to install kjots in 16.04. cheers.

Comment: kjot is not available on 16.04 repos. This answer is clearly wrong. But `kdepim-doc` seems to replace it